# Dealing with frequency in neural network input

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I have a name database with frequency of a name. Eg:

```
Madura,1064
```

I want to use this frequency parameter along with the name, as an input to my neural network since it indicates how strong a particular name is. But this frequency value is only available in the training dataset.

How can I provide frequency, something like a weight for my input, to the neural network?

Comment: I don't think the problem requires NN

Comment: This is not the whole problem. I have to use NN and I want to use the frequency as kind a weight for my input as it is a powerful information

Comment: Then I think you need to specify the whole problem for a  better solution

Answer (score 1):

One option is encoding each name as a separate input node and the activation of that node would be the standardized value (scaled between 0 and 1). This would convert the frequency to rate. If the total number of names is 8723, the `Madura` input node would have a value of 0.12197 (1064/8723).